# How to setExtremes in xAxis event handler?

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to setExtremes in the xAxis event handler below and I am getting the Uncaught TypeError.
How can I setExtremes in the xAxis event handler?

```
xAxis: {
    events: {
        setExtremes: function (e) {
            if (e.trigger === "navigator") {
                    forceRebuildSeries(); //Get all data points

                    // Set Extremes (redisplay with new data points)
                    this.chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(e.min, e.max);  //Uncaught TypeError: Property 'setExtremes' of object #<Object> is not a function 
            }
        }
    }
},
```

I would appreciate any help or workaround available.
Thanks.

Comment: But what would you like to achieve? After setting range / set extremes what should be done?

Comment: The idea is to redisplay the chart as Line Chart if the duration selected from the Navigator bar is greater than 28 days. This would display a more granular tooltip and also prevent HighCharts from averaging the values when it redraws the chart. The .setExtremes(e.min, e.max) is to maintain the values selected by the user from the Navigator bar.

Comment: you don't need to maintain anything.  The user selects a range and then the callback is triggered.  The callback doesn't need to set them again.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is it bit late, just wanted to add my answer to future visitors.

Highchart doesn't allow to call setExtremes from inside the setExtremes eventhandler in order to avoid an endless loop. That's why you get the error.

You can, however, insert a timeout in order to work around this protection:

```
 xAxis: {
     events: {
         setExtremes: function (e) {
             if (e.trigger === "navigator") {
                 var c = this;
                 setTimeout(function() {
                     forceRebuildSeries(); //Get all data points

                     // Set Extremes (redisplay with new data points)
                     c.chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(e.min, e.max);  

                 }, 1);
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for solving this. Upon inspecion of the axis during the event, I saw that axis.setExtremes was simply null, but this was infuriating because there was no explanation why. I understand now that this is done to protect us from ourselves, but in my case this is a hassle -- this should be left up to the developer (or have a 'safeZoom' flag that one can set that would disable the default behavior).

Comment: +1 for pointing out the "protection" behavior of Highcharts, it was really frustrating to see this unexpected behavior and have no idea why

Answer (score 0):

It looks like highcharts is actually setting all of the properties of the xAxis object to null for the duration of the callback.  You shouldn't need to do this though you can probably just comment out the line giving the error and be fine